# Translating: だからというのもあったが

Tags: translation

> みなみがマネージャーになったのは、夏の都予選に負けて三年生が引退した直後だった。
>   **だからというのもあったが**、この時期の練習にはほとんどの部員が参加していなかった。

Hello there, I'm trying to translate the above in to English, and am struggling to pick apart this expression: だからというのもあったが. From what I can fathom so far:
Minami became manager straight after the third years retired after losing the summer preliminary matches. (There was also the fact of 'just because of this'??) but almost none of the club members had turned up for practice this term.)
Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I would translate that as "Partially because of this".

The だから is used here to mean "as a result of this" (referring back to the fact that the team lost and the manager retired).

The というのもあった is indicating that this isn't entirely the reason why.

I think the だから here might be a bit colloquial.

In colloquial speech you can use だから to refer back to the thing you just mentioned.

Example:

> 喉の痛み、頭はずきずき、鼻は常にふさがった状態。
>
> 無理をすれば仕事できるんだろうけど、無理をする理由がない。
>
> **だから**会社を休んだ。

The だから in the above phrase is referring back to the reason given in the sentence before.